# android receiver not being called

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have an android application and I have a receiver from `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` which is never called.

I put a breakpoint on the `AlaramReceiver.java` and never stepped into. 
I checked the case and how it spelled the receiver class name.

I will add my manifest and the java classes linked.

Thank for your help.

Manifest :

```
 <receiver android:name="fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.service.android.OnAlarmReceiver_">
```

AlarmReceiver_.class :

```
public final class OnAlarmReceiver_
    extends OnAlarmReceiver
{


}
```

AlamarReceiver.java :

```
@EReceiver
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String LOG_MESSAGE_ON_RECEIVE = "startWakefulService with context and DataDownloadIntentServiceFactory.getIntentAlarmReceived";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(OnAlarmReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), LOG_MESSAGE_ON_RECEIVE);
        startWakefulService(context, DataDownloadIntentServiceFactory.getIntentAlarmReceived(context, null));
    }

}
```

DataDownloadIntentServiceFactory.java :

```
package fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.service.android;

import com.effitic.delegates.Action;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;

/**
 * Cette classe crée les différents services Android de mise à jour des positions. <br>
 * <br>
 * Copyright : Copyright (c) 2013 <br>
 * <br>
 * Société : CLS (Collecte Localisation Satellites)
 * 
 * @author Effitic
 * @version Revision: 1.1.0.02 - Date: 2014-01-15
 */
public final class DataDownloadIntentServiceFactory {

    /**
     * Constructeur.
     */
    private DataDownloadIntentServiceFactory() {
        super();
    }

    public static Intent getIntentNetworkStateChanged(Context context, boolean networkAvailable) {
        Intent dataDownloadIntentService = createIntent(context, null, DataDownloadIntentService.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED);
        dataDownloadIntentService.putExtra(DataDownloadIntentService.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED, networkAvailable);
        return dataDownloadIntentService;
    }

    private static Intent createIntent(Context context, ResultReceiver resultReceiver, String type) {
        Intent dataDownloadIntentService = DataDownloadIntentService_.intent(context).get();
        dataDownloadIntentService.putExtra(DataDownloadIntentService.TYPE, type);
        dataDownloadIntentService.putExtra(DataDownloadIntentService.RESULT_RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
        return dataDownloadIntentService;
    }

    public static Intent getIntentAlarmReceived(Context context, final Action<Object> refreshFinishedHandler) {
        ResultReceiver resultReceiver = new ResultReceiver(null) {
            @Override
            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, android.os.Bundle resultData) {
                if (refreshFinishedHandler != null) {
                    refreshFinishedHandler.execute(null);
                }
            };
        };

        Intent dataDownloadIntentService = createIntent(context, resultReceiver, DataDownloadIntentService.ALARM_RECEIVED);
        return dataDownloadIntentService;
    }

    public static Intent getIntentRefresh(Context context, final Action<Object> refreshFinishedHandler) {
        ResultReceiver resultReceiver = new ResultReceiver(null) {
            @Override
            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, android.os.Bundle resultData) {
                if (refreshFinishedHandler != null) {
                    refreshFinishedHandler.execute(null);
                }
            };
        };
        Intent dataDownloadIntentService = createIntent(context, resultReceiver, DataDownloadIntentService.REFRESH);
        return dataDownloadIntentService;
    }

    public static Intent getIntentBootCompleteReceived(Context context) {
        Intent dataDownloadIntentService = createIntent(context, null, DataDownloadIntentService.BOOT_COMPLETE_RECEIVED);
        return dataDownloadIntentService;
    }

    public static <T extends ResultReceiver> T getResultReceiverFromIntent(Intent intent, Class<T> clazz) {
        Parcelable o = intent.getParcelableExtra(DataDownloadIntentService.RESULT_RECEIVER);
        if (clazz.isInstance(o)) {
            return clazz.cast(o);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

my manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="51" android:versionName="1.3.01-SNAPSHOT" package="fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
    <!-- permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!-- pour le stockages des tuiles de carto -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <application android:allowBackup="false" android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/notif" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.view.application.CLSApplication_" android:theme="@style/AppTheme2">
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.view.activity.MapViewActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.view.activity.PanelFragmentActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <service android:name="fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.service.android.DataDownloadIntentService_"/>
        <receiver android:name="fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.service.android.OnBootReceiver_">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.service.android.OnNetworkStateChangedReceiver_">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.service.android.OnAlarmReceiver_"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct time and type for your alarm? Where is the `<receiver>` element in the manifest? It needs to be between the `<application>` tags, but not inside any others, like `<activity>` or `<service>`.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I checked and it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my PlanifyAlarmHandler

I had :

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent();
alarmIntent.setClassName("fr.cls.mobility.service.android", "OnAlarmReceiver_");
```

instead of

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver_.class);
```

Now it's working.
Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified the intent filter for the receiver in manifest. Without the intent filter it does not know when to trigger or otherwise you need to invoke it explicitly

```
<receiver android:name="fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.service.android.OnAlarmReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.YOUR_INTENT_ACTION" />
        <!--If you want to watch network connectivity state-->
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

otherwise you have to invoke it explicitly

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), fr.cls.mobility.myclsdroiddata.service.android.OnAlarmReceiver.class);
sendBroadcast(intent);`
```

Comment: I add the intent-filter with the CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE line. For the intent action it's already done by code. But still not working.